# Meaning of **power** in this context

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence, context

I've recently come across this sentence in which I've managed to understand all of the new words for me except for the last one - **power**. After looking it up in several dictionaries I still haven't figured out what its meaning here is.

> *Filming the movie on location in New York and San Francisco and on an elaborate backlot in Los Angeles adds a verisimilitude that the filmmakers hope will offer a different kind of **power**.*

Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: In my humble opinion, the writer of that phrase likely meant to use the word "energy" instead of power.

Comment: Who knows what the writer meant? The meaning is vacuous, vague, or unclear.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the term power is referencing the impact to the viewer to suspend disbelief and be figuratively transported into the film.

I would point to the use of verisimilitude used earlier in the phrase to establish the intended impact of the "power".

Building off of that earlier phrase, I believe the power is akin to the phrase, "a powerful statement". In this context, power is used as a synonym to impactful, with strong meaning and emotional content.